# Maximum data that can be stored / downloaded over the net thorugh my app ? Any limitations for sandbox?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, download, sandbox

I am designing a music player in which I will download songs and store in my device.

I know that my app size should be less than 2GB according to iTunes Guidelines, my question that I wanted to know is the maximum songs that can be stored, or is allowed for iOS programmers. Is there any limitations as such?

Answer (score 1):

The only limit for downloads is the available free space on the iDevice.

There is an additional clause in the Appstore Review Guidelines that you may need to consider though:

```
9.3
Audio streaming content over a cellular network may not use more than 5MB over 5 minutes
```